# Why doesn't jquery change my background-color?

Tags: jquery

The following script doesn't execute

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("mte").css("background-color", "red");
</script>
<body>
<div id='mte'>test 123</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your script runs, the tag has not been created yet. Put your script after the div tag. Also hash symbol was missing in jQuery expression.

```
<div id='mte'>test 123</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#mte").css("background-color", "red");
</script>
```

Otherwise use `$(document).ready()` method, so the script will run only after page is loaded with all tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mte").css("background-color", "red");
    });
</script>
<div id='mte'>test 123</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("mte").style.backgroundColor = "red";
</script>
<body>
<div id='mte'>test 123</div>
</body>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("mte").style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
doesn't change the background color why is that?

Comment: you need to have it activate

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function changeRed() {
document.getElementById("mte").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
window.onload = changeRed
</script>
<body>
<div id='mte'>test 123</div>

Answer (score 0):

**The jQuery selector is not correct.**

You should select it with this:

```
$("#mte")
```

That's to select elements with IDs. It's exactly the same as CSS. You were trying to select a list of HTML elements with the tag name `mte` which doesn't exist. Similarly, class selectors are preceded with a period or a full stop (`.`).

Full code is the following:

```
$("#mte").css("background": "#ff0000");
```

Also, if you are using the selection more than once, assign the selection to a constant.

```
const mte = $("#mte");
mte.css("background": "#ff0000");
```

See W3 School's jQuery selector guide: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<body>
<div id='mte'>test 123</div>
</body>

<script>
 $("#mte").css("background-color", "red");
</script>
```